# Illegal XML Code Error in Google Apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function hello() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var ap = UiApp.createApplication.setTitle(<'HEY!'>);
ap.add(ap.createLabel('Hello World'));
ss.show(ap); 
}
```

// It says illegal XML error in whatever line I move } to. :( Why this error ?

Comment: Look closely to the parameter you pass to `setTitle` - I guess you meant `<` and `>` to be part of the string?

Answer (score 0):

Avoid <> in .setTitle(), as you only need to pass string.

You have missed brackets () after .createApplication

You have also called .getActiveSheet(), instead of that you need to call .getActiveSpreadsheet()

So instead of:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var ap = UiApp.createApplication.setTitle(<'HEY!'>);
```

it should be:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ap = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('HEY!');
```

Try the following code:

```
function hello() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ap = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('HEY!');
  ap.add(ap.createLabel('Hello World'));
  ss.show(ap); 
};
```